# When all the asyn functions inside a finite loop are done

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I need a way to execute `next()` only after all the asyn functions inside a finite loop are done executing.

```
Schema.pre('construct', function(next) { // << next()
    var users = [123,234,345,456,...]
    users.forEach(function(user) {
        db.async_FindbyID(user, function(err, user){
            this.users.push(user);
            // can't put next() here or it'll be executed after the fist iteration alone        
        }.bind(something));
    });
    // can't put next() here because it'll be executed regardless of db.async_FindbyID
});
```

How do I make `next()` call from inside of, and only after `db.async_FindbyID` is done executing on every `user`?

Comment: does async_FindbyId() return a promise?

Comment: @Hrishi No, I think. it's a [mongoose findById](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById)

Comment: Oh well, then what you could do, something that comes to mind, is if you are using rsvp.js or something similar, is to wrap your code in a promise whose resolver function is the whole thing starting from user.foreach  and then use the .then(function() { blah })) syntax to execute the code after everything is processed. Can you do that in your case?

Comment: learning about [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) just now. Reading up on it. Thanks, looks intriguing.

Comment: Promises are probably the most promising solution. I used to do callbacks, but recently I find promises to be cleaner

Comment: @myself Just found out that [Mongoose actually does do promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep a count of users processed and when you've processed the last user, run next.

```
Schema.pre('construct', function(next) { // << next()
    var users = [123,234,345,456,...]
    var processed = 0;
    users.forEach(function(user) {
        db.async_FindbyID(user, function(user){
            this.users.push(user);

            if (++processed == users.length) {
                next();
            }
        }.bind(something));
    });
});
```

Comment: That is correct, however one should not that in case of an error, if the callback is not called, `next` will also never be called.